# Meaning of "carry over"?

Tags: word-meaning

In the following quote:

> "...Up to 400 housing units annually for ten years, with any unused units carried over each year?"

Am I correct in understanding the "carry over" as:

- If for a year there are 100 units unused, then the year after that there will still be up to 400 new housing units being made available in addition to the 100 from the year before.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. To "carry over" is to include unused items from one period, group, or other distinguishable set into the subsequent set. Sometimes the phrase used will be "roll over". These phrases are usually used when the portion carrying over is in addition to the predetermined amount for the next set.